# When installing mods, release does not show up in 'Use version:' list

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As the title states, whenever I try to install mods (Renaming folder, installing mods, etc.), the newly-created (modded) folder does not appear in the 'Use Version:' list on the launcher.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename 4 things:

- The folder
- The .json file
- The .jar file
- The "id" inside the .json file

[image]

If any of these are not changed, the version will not show up.

Comment: Oh >.> I forgot to rename the folder itself...